Assistance Needed with Implementing Conditional Okta Login in Multisite Application During Migration
I have a multisite application with login functionality, utilizing Okta login for certain sites while keeping others open to all users. Currently, I'm in the process of migrating from Optimizely 11 to 12. I'm seeking guidance on how to implement conditional Okta login, where one site necessitates login functionality while another remains accessible to all users.
Below are the configure services and configure methods within the startup.cs file. Upon further investigation, I added an onsignoutevent, but it seems to be causing a loop, resulting in a "Too many redirect" error.
Any insights or assistance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (_webHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Path.Combine(_webHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "App_Data"));

            services.Configure<SchedulerOptions>(options => options.Enabled = false);
        }

        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddResponseCaching();

        services
            //.AddCmsAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddCms()
            .AddAlloy() //Service collections Extensions
            .AddFind()
            //.AddAdminUserRegistration()// this is commented coz i need okta authentication rather than optimizely's default login
            .AddEmbeddedLocalization<Startup>();


        services.AddMvc();
        if (!_webHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            services.AddCmsCloudPlatformSupport(_configuration);
        }

        services.AddCors(opt =>
        {
            opt.AddPolicy(name: "CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
        services.AddContentDeliveryApi();
        services.AddAlloyHideTabs();

        // Required by Wangkanai.Detection to handle multiple devices
        services.AddDetection();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict;
            options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always;
        });
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "okta.auth";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie("okta.auth", options =>
            {
                options.Events.OnSignedIn = async ctx =>
                {
                    if (ctx.Principal?.Identity is ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity)
                    {
                        // Syncs user and roles so they are available to the CMS
                        var synchronizingUserService = ctx
                            .HttpContext
                            .RequestServices
                            .GetRequiredService<ISynchronizingUserService>();

                        await synchronizingUserService.SynchronizeAsync(claimsIdentity);
                    }
                };
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "okta.auth";
                options.SignOutScheme = "okta.auth";
                options.ClientId = _configuration["Okta:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = _configuration["Okta:ClientSecret"];
                options.Authority = _configuration["Okta:Authority"];
                options.SignedOutCallbackPath = _configuration["Okta:PostLogoutRedirectUrl"];
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
                options.Scope.Add(_configuration["Okta:Scopes"]);
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "groups"
                };

                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = async context =>
                    {
                        var contentLoader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
                        var urlResolver = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UrlResolver>();

                        var startPage = contentLoader.Get<StartPage>(ContentReference.StartPage);

                        if (context.Request.Path.Value != null && !context.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().Contains("episerver"))
                        {
                            context.Response.Redirect($"{startPage.LoginPage.GetPublicUrl().TrimEnd('/')}?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(context.Request.GetEncodedUrl())}");
                            context.HandleResponse();
                        }

                        if (ContentReference.StartPage.ID != 0 && context.Exception.Message.Contains("User is not assigned to the client application"))
                        {
                            context.Response.Redirect($"{urlResolver.GetUrl(startPage.LoginPage)}?loginErrorMessage={Uri.EscapeDataString("User is not assigned to the client application. Make sure the user is assigned to the application or to a group assigned to the application in Okta.")}");
                            context.HandleResponse();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync(context.Exception.Message);

                            context.HandleResponse();
                        }
                        await Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
                        {
                            context.HandleResponse();
                        }

                        // If signing out, add the id_token_hint
                        if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                        {
                            var idTokenHint = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken);

                            if (idTokenHint != null)
                            {
                                context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                            }

                            context.HandleResponse();

                            await Task.CompletedTask;
                            return;
                        }

                        var contentLoader = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IContentLoader>();

                        if (ContentReference.StartPage.ID != 0)
                        {
                            var startPage = contentLoader.Get<StartPage>(ContentReference.StartPage);
                            var loginPageUrl = startPage.LoginPage.GetPublicUrl();

                            if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().Contains("episerver") && startPage.LoginPage == null)
                            {
                                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                                context.HandleResponse();
                                return;
                            }

                            if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().Contains("episerver") && context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Epi-Auth-Flow"] == null)
                            {
                                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect($"{loginPageUrl.TrimEnd('/')}?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(context.HttpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl())}");
                                context.HandleResponse();
                                return;
                            }
                        }


                        if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 401 && context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                            context.HandleResponse();
                            return;
                        }

                        if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 401 && IsXhrRequest(context.HttpContext.Request))
                        {
                            context.HandleResponse();
                            return;
                        }

                        //context.HandleResponse();
                        await Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
                    {
                        // Handle authorization code received
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    OnTokenValidated = (ctx) =>
                    {
                        var redirectUri = new Uri(ctx.Properties.RedirectUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                        if (redirectUri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                        {
                            ctx.Properties.RedirectUri = redirectUri.PathAndQuery;
                        }

                        //// Sync user and the roles to EPiServer in the background
                        //var synchronizingUserService = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ISynchronizingUserService>();
                        ////synchronizingUserService.SynchronizeAsync(ctx.Principal);

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
            

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddTransient<ContentLocator>();

        services.AddTransient<IOktaServices>(serviceProvider => new OktaServices(serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>()!));

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.CacheProfiles.Add("PageControllerBaseOutputCacheProfile", new CacheProfile
            {
                Duration = 0,  // Cache duration in seconds. Set to 0 for no caching.
                Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None,
                NoStore = true
            });
        });
       
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }


        // Required by Wangkanai.Detection
        app.UseDetection();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        //app.UseMiddleware<RobotsMiddleware>();
        //app.UseMiddleware<MediaAssetMiddleware>();
        //app.UseMiddleware<RemoveDuplicateCookiesMiddleware>();
        //app.UseNotFoundHandler();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapContent();
        });

         app.Map("/util/logout", map =>
        {
            map.Run(async context =>
            {
                // Sign out the user
                await context.SignOutAsync();

                if (ContentReference.StartPage.ID == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var contentLoader = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IContentLoader>();
                var urlResolver = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UrlResolver>();

                var startPage = contentLoader.Get<StartPage>(ContentReference.StartPage);

                // Redirect to the start page
                context.Response.Redirect(
                    $"{context.Request.Scheme}://{context.Request.Host}{urlResolver.GetUrl(startPage)}");
            });
        });
    }

